# Trying to view deployed JSP page online. XAMP / Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, xampp

I've been using XAMP and it's features for some php sites and it's working fine.  I'm now needing to use it for JSP development for a project we're about to start working on.

So far it's functioning on my local machine in that I downloaded the sample war file from Tomcat and it deploys fine and is visible when using localhost:8080/sample.

The problem is that I can't seem to access it from a browser using the domain name.  I tried www.mydomain.com/sample but receive a 404 error.
The same when using my local IP address instead.

I've searched online for a while now and have come across a few sources that hint at integrating apache with tomcat but nothing concrete enough to try and get a working solution.

I've also tried (and miserably failed) to watch the video that is referenced in a few other questions.

Any help is hugely appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because tomcat works on port 8080 unlike apache - when you run php sites they are just behind the apache which is visible on port 80 (which the default one in browsers), you can go through "http://mydomain.com:8080/sample" and it would work the same as through localhost

you can also change tomcat's settings and change it's connector's port from 8080 to 80, and then it would work as you expected

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks for taking the time to help.  I tried what you suggested with the port but get an error message saying it can't connect to the server.  The server is definitely online though.  Anything else I might need to do?

Comment: where and how did you change the settings?

Comment: I didn't touch the settings, just tried what you suggested with the domain and port number

Comment: oh, ok - anyway hard to tell, there might be hundreds of reasons for that, 1. localhost:8080/sample must respond locally, and then if no firewall is blocking inbound requests from "world" then it should work

Comment: ah.  Firewall is disabled.  Not sure what else to look for. :(

Comment: can you tell the domain name?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47075/discussion-between-steve-green-and-kamil-mikolajczyk)

Comment: Router was blocking the port -.- Thanks so much fr help.  I'll change the config setting for tomcat to change port to 80 like apache.